# Win32 threading

Tags: c, winapi, thread-safety

My application uses `CreateThread` to create a secondary *(and only)* thread that executes every `10ms`, like the following *pseudocode*:

```
map<string, int32_t> a_map;

DWORD WINAPI Table::manual_action_execute_thread(LPVOID lpParameter) {
   while(Table::manual_action_execute_thread_run) {
      ...
      if (!Table::automatic_action_execute_inprogress) {
         ...
      }
      ...
      if (a_map["blah"] == 0) {
         ...
      }
      ...
      Sleep(10);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

The variables are declared as following:

```
static volatile bool manual_action_execute_thread_run;
static volatile bool automatic_action_execute_inprogress;
```

The first one takes the value of `true` before even start my thread so i don't use locking on this. The second takes a `false` at first.

I am using `::automatic_action_execute_inprogress` to control some behaviour on *second thread* which only changes on the *main thread*.

**QUESTION(s):**

**1)** Since i only update `::automatic_action_execute_inprogress` on *main thread* and just reading it on *second thread* i still need to *lock it* first using `EnterCriticalSection`? Or the locking is only restricted to the shared variables that are changed on both threads?

**2)** What about a `<map>` that's used on multiple threads and modified by just one? Certainly i have to lock it with `EnterCriticalSection` whenever changes but what about `read` access? Should i lock it *when i read from it* (like `if (a_map["foo"] == 0)`) if can change even by a single thread? Like this for example?

```
EnterCriticalSection(&cs);
   bool val = a_map["foo"];
LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);

   if (val == 0) {
      ...
   }
```

Comment: The variable must be defined as an atomic variable, or you need to lock it, otherwise you get undefined behavior, due to a data race. The qualifier volatile does **not** make a variable atomic.

Comment: @2501, thanks for the comment. I am locking the variables with critical sections when i change them. What about a `<map>` used on multiple threads and modified by just one? Should i lock it whenever changes or should i lock every _read_ as well since it's non atomic?

Comment: You will have to learn what a data race is. The resources available on this website.

Comment: As long as one thread modifies the map, every single read and write must be locked.

Comment: @2501, thank you about the _read/write_ situation, i do a lot of reading so thanx for clearing this up. I am already reading this topic and applying the required fixes, just needed some clarification to avoid the usual crashes.

Comment: thanks for the downvote and especially the reason :)

Comment: @2501 i was not talking to you, i didn't added a `@`person in my comment, it goes to the anonymous that downvotes without an explanation.

Comment: @2501, sorry about that :) it probably an error or it sent automatically if there are only 2 commenters..

Comment: In addition [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd(v=vs.80).aspx) very page says that `volatile` guarantee ordering. I understand that's not standard and only VC++ specific but its obvious i'm using `winapi` and did not said anything about portability. In addition i have `VC2010+` and atomic are only supported on `VC2012` -- noone asked about the version, sorry. Thanx for all the downvotes, especially on @Mike's answer.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Since you only update your variable in one thread and just read it in other threads, and since the type of the variable is *atomic*, you do not need any locking mechanism.  All you need to do is declare it `volatile`, which you have already done.  If the variable was of a non-atomic type, (say, a `map`, or even just a 64-bit integer on a 32-bit architecture,) then you would need locking.

The C & C++ standard does not presume atomicity of operations even on simple machine-word operations like reading an `int`, but if you are using `winapi` then you are on `x86`, which guarantees it. (So, if you want to write portable code, use locking even if you are writing an `int` on one thread and only reading it from other threads.)

Comment: Thanks. So if i understand correctly, if i use `volatile` i am safe locking only  the variables that are changed on one thread, regardless if they're used elsewhere? _non-atomic_ are even simple integers like `int32_t a;` ? I am asking because i am also using some `<map>` in the _secondary thread_  (not changing them in _second thread_, just reading),which i cannot set them as `volatile`. Should i lock them before _using_ them i.e. like `if (mymap["bla"] == 0)` because they're non atomic?

Comment: ..or need to lock the `<map>` on _main thread_ when i modify it before use it on _second thread_ since it's non atomic?

Comment: yes, of course, both modifying and reading a map is very far from being an atomic operation, so it certainly requires locking.

Comment: Operations on an int32_t are atomic on 32-bit systems and above.

Comment: Note that with the map, you are modifying the *contents* of the map, not the map itself, so it needs to be protected with a lock, it does not need to be volatile.  (And as you already know, it can't.)

Comment: @MikeNakis That's invalid reasoning. You take a hardware implementation and apply it to to a language (and its compiler). In C, having a data race will cause undefined behavior, regardless of what the hardware does. You answer seems to suggest the same as your comment. Thus it is not correct.

Comment: On x86 hardware the other CPUs will eventually see a volatile variable change. But all kinds of things don't work correctly without atomic operations. For example if thread 1 sets x = 2 and y = 5 then thread 2 could see y = 5 for quite a long time and then see x = 2 sometime later. No ordering guarantees. And on other CPU types there are no guarantees at all.

Comment: @2501 that's perfectly valid reasoning considering that the OP is specifically working with the `winapi`.  This API is only available on architectures on which machine word reads and writes are atomic, provided that they are word-aligned, which is something that the C compiler generally guarantees.  Tons of code have been written all over the world that rely on this, and they work.

Comment: @ZanLynx Doesn't the use of `volatile` guarantee ordering?  (In any case, the OP's question is not about ordering.)

Comment: That's an argument from common practice. Just because such code works for some, doesn't make it defined or teach-worthy. What's worse, is, that such arguments produce silent bugs.

Comment: @MikeNakis No, volatile has nothing to do with ordering. And that is, one of the ways non-atomic code will have bugs on a atomic machine.

Comment: thank you @MikeNakis and all for the valuable information :) I don't know about ordering and if there's a problem about that. Are you saying if i don't use `std::atomic` i'll have ordering problem even with simple integers?

Comment: @2501 I amended my answer to take your comments into account.  I hope I am covering you.

Comment: @user6096479 well, 2501 is saying that the use of volatile does not guarantee ordering.  I find that hard to believe, but I cannot research it right now, so let's take his word for it.  In this context, "no ordering" means that if you set x to 1 and then y to 2 from one thread, you should not expect to observe x turning into 1 first, and y turning into 2 afterwards.  You might observe y turning into 2 first, and x turning into 1 afterwards.  If you are not planning to be doing anything that complex, you are certainly fine.

Comment: @MikeNakis, aha i see, thank you... Well even if this occurs still requires at least 3 threads and 2 writers or 2 threads with multiple writing on one or both of them? I have to see my code if doing such things and fix. Thank for for yet another explanation :)

Comment: you can get ordering issues with just one writer and one reader.

Comment: You have made no effort at all to explain what `volatile` means, and how it can guarantee correctness of this code. The downvotes reflect that it is not possible to do that, given the code in your answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the OP is already using `volatile`, he did not ask what it does.  Code in my answer?  What code in my answer?

Comment: OK, I meant when you said, "All you need to do is declare it volatile, which you have already done."

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, i kinda know what `volatile` does. It forces the compiler to not optimize these variables which could prove harmful with threads, isn't ? If the reason for `volatile` discussion is _ordering_ is there a reference where it says `volatile` does not guarantee ordering? Im only working on Windows for this specific program if that matters

Comment: @user6096479 Well, based on that comment, you don't know what `volatile` does

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Quoting from the C++ Standard ($7.1.5.1/8)

`[..] volatile is a hint to the implementation to avoid aggressive optimization involving the object because the value of the object might be changed by means undetectable by an implementation.[...]`

Comment: And you read that as, "It forces the compiler to not optimize these variables which could prove harmful with threads, isn't?"

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, what is the error of what i said? other than the 'it forces' against the 'it hints'. Does the compiler avoid optimization of these variables or it does not? Im not a regular reader of the standard anyway.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135564/discussion-on-answer-by-mike-nakis-win32-threading).